# Postman using string contains text with an environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, postman, postman-collection-runner

Hopefully this is super simple but I could not find a direct answer for this anywhere I have looked.

In Postman I want to use the below test to make sure the body is returning the correct text.

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("string_you_want_to_search");
});
```

But I want to easily switch between a Dev and Test environment, run the test and validate that I get a dev URL back and a test URL back.

So lets say for example I have a variable called **{{foobar}}**.  In test the URL for that variable would be **foo-test.bar.com** and in Dev it would be **foo-dev.bar.com** .  I then modify the test to take the variable instead of the string like so:

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("{{foobar}}");
});
```

I assume I can use one env variable to check both urls just by switching the environment. But I must not have the syntax correct because I get back a long error that begins with "AssertionError: expected '\r\n\r\n"

Can anyone provide assistance?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the response text value and what is `foobar` referencing? I don’t think that you can use that `{{...}}` syntax in the tests. You want to use `pm.variables.get('foobar')` instead. You can also use the Postman Console to log out the response and the assert value to debug it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use environment variables inside your tests you must use the **pm.environment.get("varName")** method, so your test should look like:

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
   pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(pm.environment.get("foobar"));
});
```